# Почему RF модель показала точность 0%?

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, kaggle

Имеется [фрейм](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data)

Составлен некоторый код обработки данных и обучена модель.
Обучающая выборка дает некоторый результат, тестовая выборка дает 0%.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from scipy import stats
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')


# In[34]:


df_train = pd.read_csv('D:\___/train.csv')


# In[35]:


df_train.info()
df_train.columns


# In[36]:


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))

sns.heatmap(df_train.corr(), cmap= sns.color_palette(palette="RdBu"),linewidths=0.5,annot=False, ax=ax)


# In[37]:


df_train.corr


# In[38]:


df_train['SalePrice'].describe()


# In[39]:


sns.distplot(df_train['SalePrice']);


# In[40]:


print("Skewness: %f" % df_train['SalePrice'].skew())
print("Kurtosis: %f" % df_train['SalePrice'].kurt())


# In[41]:


var = 'GrLivArea'
data = pd.concat([df_train['SalePrice'], df_train[var]], axis=1)
data.plot.scatter(x=var, y='SalePrice', ylim=(0,800000));


# In[42]:


var = 'TotalBsmtSF'
data = pd.concat([df_train['SalePrice'], df_train[var]], axis=1)
data.plot.scatter(x=var, y='SalePrice', ylim=(0,800000));


# In[43]:


var = 'OverallQual'
data = pd.concat([df_train['SalePrice'], df_train[var]], axis=1)
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
fig = sns.boxplot(x=var, y="SalePrice", data=data)
fig.axis(ymin=0, ymax=800000);


# In[44]:


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))

corrmat = df_train.corr()
k = 16 #number of variables for heatmap
cols = corrmat.nlargest(k, 'SalePrice')['SalePrice'].index
cm = np.corrcoef(df_train[cols].values.T)
sns.set(font_scale=1.25)
hm = sns.heatmap(cm, cbar=True, annot=True, square=True, fmt='.2f', annot_kws={'size': 16}, yticklabels=cols.values, xticklabels=cols.values, ax=ax)
plt.show()


# In[45]:


sns.set()
cols = ['SalePrice', 'OverallQual', 'GrLivArea', 'GarageCars', 'TotalBsmtSF', 'FullBath', 'YearBuilt']
sns.pairplot(df_train[cols], size = 2.5)
plt.show();


# In[46]:


total = df_train.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
percent = (df_train.isnull().sum()/df_train.isnull().count()).sort_values(ascending=False)
missing_data = pd.concat([total, percent], axis=1, keys=['Total', 'Percent'])
missing_data.head(20)


# In[47]:


df_train = df_train.drop((missing_data[missing_data['Total'] > 1]).index,1)
df_train = df_train.drop(df_train.loc[df_train['Electrical'].isnull()].index)
df_train.isnull().sum().max()


# In[48]:


saleprice_scaled = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df_train['SalePrice'][:,np.newaxis]);
low_range = saleprice_scaled[saleprice_scaled[:,0].argsort()][:10]
high_range= saleprice_scaled[saleprice_scaled[:,0].argsort()][-10:]
print('outer range (low) of the distribution:')
print(low_range)
print('\nouter range (high) of the distribution:')
print(high_range)


# In[49]:


var = 'GrLivArea'
data = pd.concat([df_train['SalePrice'], df_train[var]], axis=1)
data.plot.scatter(x=var, y='SalePrice', ylim=(0,800000));


# In[50]:


df_train.sort_values(by = 'GrLivArea', ascending = False)[:2]


# In[51]:


df_train = df_train.drop(df_train[df_train['Id'] == 1299].index)
df_train = df_train.drop(df_train[df_train['Id'] == 524].index)


# In[52]:


var = 'GrLivArea'
data = pd.concat([df_train['SalePrice'], df_train[var]], axis=1)
data.plot.scatter(x=var, y='SalePrice', ylim=(0,800000));


# In[53]:


var = 'TotalBsmtSF'
data = pd.concat([df_train['SalePrice'], df_train[var]], axis=1)
data.plot.scatter(x=var, y='SalePrice', ylim=(0,800000));


# In[54]:


sns.distplot(df_train['SalePrice'], fit=norm);
fig = plt.figure()


# In[55]:


res = stats.probplot(df_train['SalePrice'], plot=plt)


# In[56]:



df_train['SalePrice'] = np.log(df_train['SalePrice'])


# In[57]:



sns.distplot(df_train['SalePrice'], fit=norm);
fig = plt.figure()


# In[58]:


res = stats.probplot(df_train['SalePrice'], plot=plt)


# In[59]:



df_train['HasBsmt'] = pd.Series(len(df_train['TotalBsmtSF']), index=df_train.index)
df_train['HasBsmt'] = 0 
df_train.loc[df_train['TotalBsmtSF']>0,'HasBsmt'] = 1


# In[60]:



df_train.loc[df_train['HasBsmt']==1,'TotalBsmtSF'] = np.log(df_train['TotalBsmtSF'])


# In[61]:



sns.distplot(df_train[df_train['TotalBsmtSF']>0]['TotalBsmtSF'], fit=norm);
fig = plt.figure()
res = stats.probplot(df_train[df_train['TotalBsmtSF']>0]['TotalBsmtSF'], plot=plt)


# In[62]:


df_train.info()


# In[70]:


    data_features = df_train.drop("Id", axis = 1)
X, y = df_train.drop (["SalePrice"], axis = 1), df_train["SalePrice"]
FF = pd.get_dummies(X)


# In[76]:



# In[80]:


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


# In[92]:


Xnp = np.array(FF)
ynp = np.array(y)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split (Xnp, ynp, test_size=0.5)
print(FF.shape, X_train.shape, X_test.shape)
print(y.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)


# In[90]:


from sklearn import preprocessing

lab_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder() #выдавало ValueError: Unknown label type: ‘continuous’
tse = lab_enc.fit_transform(y_train)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit (X_train, tse)


# In[91]:


print ("Train accuracy:", (model.predict(X_train) == tse).mean())
print ("Val accuracy:", (model.predict(X_test) == y_test).mean())
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь предсказать / классифицировать __уникальный__ `ID` по данным, которые даны для задачи __регрессии__??

Comment: Я убрал ID, опорной стала колонка SalePrice.
После разбиения на тренировочную/тестовую, по тестовой все также 0. Хотя и там и там массивы данных выглядят схоже.
Всё, спасибо. Разобрался. Точность, такая же как на титанике. В конце списка участников 8(

Comment: Вы все еще используете алгоритм классификации в задаче по регрессии??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь использовать алгоритм классификации (которые предсказывают дискретные значения) для предсказания непрерывных данных (таких как цена).

Для таких задач надо использовать один из [алгоритмов регрессии](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html).