# Несовпадение размеров матриц при обучении предиктивной модели и предсказания

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Имеется 2 pd.frame  ([Почему RF модель показала точность 0%?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1009035/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-rf-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-0)

Что делать, если при преобразовании Pd.get_dummies нарушает соответствие размерности матриц(изначально фреймы равны) ?
попытка предсказания:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from scipy import stats
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import linear_model

df_train = pd.read_csv('D:\Kaggle\House prices/train.csv')
df_test = pd.read_csv('D:\Kaggle\House prices/test.csv')

total = df_train.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
percent = (df_train.isnull().sum()/df_train.isnull().count()).sort_values(ascending=False)
missing_data_train = pd.concat([total, percent], axis=1, keys=['Total', 'Percent'])

df_train = df_train.drop((missing_data_train[missing_data_train['Total'] > 1]).index,1)
df_train = df_train.drop(df_train.loc[df_train['Electrical'].isnull()].index)

df_test = df_test.drop((missing_data_train[missing_data_train['Total'] > 1]).index,1)
df_test = df_test.drop(df_test.loc[df_test['Electrical'].isnull()].index)

saleprice_scaled = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df_train['SalePrice'][:,np.newaxis]);

df_test.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
df_test = df_test.astype(int, errors='ignore')

df_train.sort_values(by = 'GrLivArea', ascending = False)[:2]

df_train = df_train.drop(df_train[df_train['Id'] == 1299].index)
df_train = df_train.drop(df_train[df_train['Id'] == 524].index)

df_train['SalePrice'] = np.log(df_train['SalePrice'])

data_features = df_train.drop("Id", axis = 1)
X, y = data_features.drop (["SalePrice"], axis = 1), df_train["SalePrice"]
FF = pd.get_dummies(X)

Xnp = np.array(FF)
ynp = np.array(y)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split (Xnp, ynp, test_size=0.5)

lab_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
tsy = lab_enc.fit_transform(y_train)
data_features2

reg = linear_model.Ridge(alpha=.5)
pred=reg.fit(X_train,y_train) 

data_features2 = df_test.drop("Id", axis = 1)

FF2 = pd.get_dummies(data_features2)
FF2
Xnp2 = np.array(FF2)

an=pred.predict(Xnp2)

ValueError: shapes (1459,205) and (219,) not aligned: 205 (dim 1) != 219 (dim 0)
```

Comment: чтобы дать ответ на данный вопрос надо создать небольшой пример исходного DataFrame, потом показать как вы делаете PIVOT, чтобы помочь воспроизвести ошибку. Если мы сделаем это за вас, то очень высока вероятность того, что данное решение не будет работать для ваших данных  по причине различия структуры исходных данных...

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Добавил код. Он же: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1009035/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-rf-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-0?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина ошибки лежит в природе алгоритма `One Hot Encoding`, который используется в `pd.get_dummies()`. А именно в том, что число результирующих столбцов зависит от набора уникальных строковых значений.

Воспроизведение ошибки:

```
In [89]: train = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["a", "b", "c"], "col2": ["aa", "bb", "cc"]})

In [90]: test = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["a", "c"], "col2": ["aa", "cc"]})

In [91]: train
Out[91]:
  col1 col2
0    a   aa
1    b   bb
2    c   cc

In [92]: test
Out[92]:
  col1 col2
0    a   aa
1    c   cc

In [93]: pd.get_dummies(train)
Out[93]:
   col1_a  col1_b  col1_c  col2_aa  col2_bb  col2_cc
0       1       0       0        1        0        0
1       0       1       0        0        1        0
2       0       0       1        0        0        1

In [94]: pd.get_dummies(test)
Out[94]:
   col1_a  col1_c  col2_aa  col2_cc
0       1       0        1        0
1       0       1        0        1
```

Как видно из примера, после `pd.get_dummies()`, число столбцов в `pd.get_dummies(test)` - 4, а в `pd.get_dummies(train)` - 6.

---

Тоже самое для вашего датасета:

сначала выберем только строковые (`dtype == "object"`) столбцы:

```
In [95]: cols = df_train.columns[df_train.dtypes.eq("object")]

In [96]: print(cols)
Index(['MSZoning', 'Street', 'LotShape', 'LandContour', 'Utilities', 'LotConfig', 'LandSlope', 'Neighborhood',
       'Condition1', 'Condition2', 'BldgType', 'HouseStyle', 'RoofStyle', 'RoofMatl', 'Exterior1st', 'Exterior2nd',
       'ExterQual', 'ExterCond', 'Foundation', 'Heating', 'HeatingQC', 'CentralAir', 'Electrical', 'KitchenQual',
       'Functional', 'PavedDrive', 'SaleType', 'SaleCondition'],
      dtype='object')
```

делаем `One Hot Encoding` / `DUMMY` encoding:

```
In [97]: train_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df_train[cols])

In [98]: test_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df_test[cols])
```

число столбцов датасетов после кодирования не совпадает:

```
In [99]: train_dummies.shape
Out[99]: (1457, 186)

In [100]: test_dummies.shape
Out[100]: (1459, 172)
```

столбцы отсутствующие в `test_dummies`:

```
In [101]: train_dummies.columns.difference(test_dummies.columns)
Out[101]:
Index(['Condition2_RRAe', 'Condition2_RRAn', 'Condition2_RRNn', 'Electrical_Mix', 'Exterior1st_ImStucc',
       'Exterior1st_Stone', 'Exterior2nd_Other', 'Heating_Floor', 'Heating_OthW', 'HouseStyle_2.5Fin',
       'RoofMatl_Membran', 'RoofMatl_Metal', 'RoofMatl_Roll', 'Utilities_NoSeWa'],
      dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 2):

[Причина расхождения числа столбцов для обучающей и тестовой выборки после кодирования `pd.get_dummies()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1010500/211923)

---

## Решение

В таких случаях удобно использовать [Hashing trick](https://booking.ai/dont-be-tricked-by-the-hashing-trick-192a6aae3087).

Есть удобный модуль [category_encoders](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/index.html), в котором реализованы все популярные алгоритмы кодирования категориальных данных:

```
import category_encoders as ce   # pip install category_encoders

encoder = ce.Hashing(n_components=4)

In [138]: encoder.fit_transform(train)
Out[138]:
   col_0  col_1  col_2  col_3
0      0      1      1      0
1      1      0      0      1
2      1      0      0      1

In [139]: encoder.fit_transform(test)
Out[139]:
   col_0  col_1  col_2  col_3
0      0      1      1      0
1      1      0      0      1
```